# How can I use LowDB in Electron without ES6

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to use LowDB with Electron in plain javascript but i have 'Must use import to load ES Module' error. I did some research but content is so old and doesn't work.
this is what i found: https://github.com/typicode/lowdb/issues/169

this is the code i got error:

**Javascript**

```
const electron = require("electron");
const { join } = require("path");
const { Low, JSONFile } = require("lowdb"); // this line gives error
const remote =
    process.type === "browser" ? electron : require("@electron/remote");
const app = electron.app ? electron.app : remote.app;
const database =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? join(__dirname, "dev_db.json")
        : join(app.getPath("userData"), "todoiva_db.storm");

// Use JSON file for storage
const adapter = new JSONFile(database);
const db = new Low(adapter);

// Read data from JSON file, this will set db.data content
db.read();
```

**The entire error:**

> App threw an error during load Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use
> import to load ES Module:
> /Users/mrocks/others/sipsak/node_modules/lowdb/lib/index.js require()
> of ES modules is not supported. require() of
> /Users/mrocks/others/sipsak/node_modules/lowdb/lib/index.js from
> /Users/mrocks/others/sipsak/database.js is an ES module file as it is
> a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module"
> which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
> Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to
> use import(), or remove "type": "module" from
> /Users/mrocks/others/sipsak/node_modules/lowdb/package.json.
>
> ```
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:370:5)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:13)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:982:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:823:12)
> at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13331)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1006:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mrocks/others/sipsak/database.js:3:27)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1110:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:10)
> ```

I just want to use LowDB without ES6.

update: I followed the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c#how-can-i-move-my-commonjs-project-to-esm) but they didn't help in solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of lowdb has become pure ESM package, so you can’t use “require”. To use lowdb without ESM, I think the only way is using the older version of lowdb. I have tested the v1.0.0 of lowdb, which can be used by “require” perfectly.

update: please this issue: https://github.com/typicode/lowdb/issues/534